# In what order are migrations executed in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I have a habit of keeping a separate Migration Class for every custom Type or Part. A lot of the time I want to attach a Taxonomy Field for the same Taxonomy to several custom Parts. Since I'm not sure which migration will run first, I have to check if the Taxonomy already exists in each migration and create it if it doesn't, leading to a lot of duplicate code. I could move my code into a service for the sake of re-usability/maintainability but it would be easier still if I knew for sure which migration was going to get executed first.

Comment: I think its in order of discovered modules and classes, just set a break point in your migrations and watch the call stack. You should see a loop somewhere in the base classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be running in order of dependency, starting with the dependency, ending with the module depending on it.

However, for this sort of thing, you might want to try recipes rather than migrations.

Comment: Thanks! So suppose I can't use a recipe for my purpose and I have a site consisting of multiple custom modules with each containing multiple migration files, I'm still not entirely sure which of those migrations is going to run first. All modules have the same dependencies and I know the order of migrations within a module is not alphabetical or by creation or modification date. I could put my migrations into a separate module and have all of my others depend on it but I think for the sake of simplicity I will just use a static method for this in the future.